# Can I turn on Fortran syntax highlight with ".h" file in vim?

Tags: vim, fortran, syntax-highlighting, header-files, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am working on a Fortran project. The author keeps all function interfaces in the ".F90" file between the "module/end module" part, and keeps all the implementation in a separate ".h" file. A "#include" command is used at the end of the module section.

I am trying to study the implementation code. Unfortunately, vim does not treat the .h file as a fortran source code, and I could not turn on the syntax highlight. Is there a way to get the syntax highlight on?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the detected syntax / filetype (probably C for `*.h` files) with

```
:setlocal filetype=fortran
```

also while opening:

```
:edit +setf\ fortran file.h
```

If you need this often (and don't usually edit C/C++ header files), you can also adapt the default filetype detection rules; cp. `:help ftdetect`.

(This all assumes you have syntax highlighting turned on via `:syntax on` in your `~/.vimrc`.)